Complex typing of a factory function returning a wrapper around a function in Typescript (generics of generics)
I want to create a factory function that takes an onOk and onErr handlers and return a wrapper around function that may throw.
const mayThrow = (fail: boolean) => {
   if (fail) {
      throw new Error('failed')
   }
   return 'ok'
}

Let's define both handler and their types
type Ok<T> = { ok: true, value: T }
type Err<E> = { ok: false, error: E }
type Result<T, E> = Ok<T> | Err<E>
const onOk = <T>(value: T): Ok<T> => ({ ok: true, value })
const onErr = <E>(error: E): Err<E> => ({ ok: false, error })


I have this factory function that I can almost type correctly.
function createSafeFactory<
   U extends (...args: any[]) => any,
   F extends (...args: any[]) => any
>(onOk: U, onErr: F) {
   return <A extends any[], T, E>(
      fn: (...args: A) => T,
      errorFn?: (error: unknown) => E
   ) => {
       return (...args: A): ReturnType<U> | ReturnType<F> => {
           try {
               const result = fn(...args)
               return onOk(result)
           } catch (e) {
               const error = errorFn ? errorFn(e) : (e as E)
               return onErr(error)
           }
       }
   }
}


const safe = createSafeFactory(onOk, onErr)
// const safe: <A extends any[], T, E>(fn: (...args: A) => T, errorFn?: ((error: unknown) => E) | undefined) => (...args: A) => Ok<unknown> | Err<unknown>

const safeFn = safe(mayThrow)
// const safeFn: (fail: boolean) => Ok<unknown> | Err<unknown>

const res = safeFn(true)
// const res: Ok<unknown> | Err<unknown>

if (res.ok) {
   const data = res.value
   // const data: unknown
}


data is unknown instead of string
What I want is the result to be typed Result<string, never> or Ok<string> | Err<never>.
The problem is here: ReturnType<U> | ReturnType<F>. I want the return type of U and F given that U and F are typed relative to T and E.
How can I achieve something like ReturnType<U<T>> | ReturnType<F<E>>

TS cannot support arbitrary high order function types like this. The only support that exists is described at ms/TS#30215. The closest you can get to this exact code is this playground link but unfortunately the returned function can only accept any[], it cannot already have been generic. If you want that you have to give up on the currying thing and write it as in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Thanks @jcalz that’s helpful. It is possible to define the final return type explicitly while letting all other types to be inferred by TS? ˋcreateSafeFactory<R, U, F>(…) { … }ˋ and when invoking the function ˋcreateSafeFacrory<Ok|Err>(…)ˋ with T, the infered return type of onOk and E the infered return type of onErr

No, you cannot explicitly annotate them; the support in ms/TS#30215 does stuff that simply cannot be expressed in the type system. The types you'd want to annotate would involve unbound type parameters. Have I fully addressed the question now? Shall I write up an answer or am I missing something? (Note I asked this question before but you didn't answer it, could you please do so, so I can know how to proceed? Thank you.)

Yes, you can, thanks for the explanation.

You cannot perform arbitrary higher order generic function type manipulation. Generally speaking TypeScript will have to give up and erase generic type parameters or instantiate them with their constraints before manipulating them. So ReturnType<> acting on the type <T>(value: T) => Ok<T> will produce Ok<unknown> because the generic type parameter T inside the function ends up being instantiated with its implicit unknown constraint.  TypeScript's type system is simply not expressive enough for this. In order to allow such things you might need higher kinded types as described in microsoft/TypeScript#1213, or instantiation types as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#50481.
There is some support for manipulating generic function types like this at the value level. That is, sometimes you can write generic functions that operate on generic functions and produce different generic functions, but you need actual functions to do this, and not just their types.  This support was implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#30215, and it's quite restrictive in what it supports. In particular:

When an argument expression in a function call is of a generic function type, the type parameters of that function type are propagated onto the result type of the call if:

the called function is a generic function that returns a function type with a single call signature,
that single call signature doesn't itself introduce type parameters, and
in the left-to-right processing of the function call arguments, no inferences have been made for any of the type parameters referenced in the contextual type for the argument expression.


Generally speaking you cannot write things in terms of function types like O extends (arg: any) => any and E extends (arg: any) => any, but instead need to write things in terms of their argument and return types like OA, OR, EA, and ER.  Unfortunately that isn't sufficient for your code to start working:
function createSafeFactory<OA, OR, EA, ER>(
    onOk: (arg: OA) => OR,
    onErr: (arg: EA) => ER
) {
    return <A extends any[]>(
        fn: (...args: A) => OA,
        errorFn?: (error: unknown) => EA
    ) => {
        return (...args: A): OR | ER => {
            try {
                const result = fn(...args)
                return onOk(result)
            } catch (e) {
                const error = errorFn ? errorFn(e) : e as EA //
                return onErr(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

const safe = createSafeFactory(onOk, onErr)
/* const safe: <A extends any[]>(
     fn: (...args: A) => unknown, 
     errorFn?: ((error: unknown) => unknown) | undefined
) => (...args: any[]) => Ok<unknown> | Err<unknown> */

(Aside: I don't know why you'd think it's okay to assume that the caught error is what onErr expects in the absence of an errorFn argument. I would think you'll see some runtime errors there, but that's off-topic.)
Oops, safe failed to be generic in the onOk or onErr types. Why? Oh, because createSafeFactory returns a function whose call signature introduces the type parameter A.  If we make the returned function non-generic, then you can get quite close to what you're looking for:
function createSafeFactory<OA, OR, EA, ER>(
    onOk: (arg: OA) => OR,
    onErr: (arg: EA) => ER
) {
    return (
        fn: (...args: any[]) => OA,
        errorFn?: (error: unknown) => EA
    ) => {
        return (...args: any[]): OR | ER => {
            try {
                const result = fn(...args)
                return onOk(result)
            } catch (e) {
                const error = errorFn ? errorFn(e) : e as EA //
                return onErr(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

const safe = createSafeFactory(onOk, onErr)
/* const safe: <T, E>(
     fn: (...args: any[]) => T, 
     errorFn?: ((error: unknown) => E) | undefined
) => (...args: any[]) => Ok<T> | Err<E> */

Here safe is now generic in T and E, the generic type parameters that were propagated from fn and errorFn arguments. And the return type is `(...args: any[]) => Ok | Err. That's sufficient for your examples to work:
const safeFn = safe(mayThrow)

const res = safeFn(true)
// const res: Ok<string> | Err<unknown>

if (res.ok) {
    const data = res.value
    // const data: string
}

but since safe's return type has forgotten about the type of args, you can also do bad stuff like
safeFn("oopsie", 123); // no error, oops


The only way I know to write code similar to this where the types work is to uncurry createSafeFactory:
function createSafeFn<OA, OR, EA, ER, A extends any[]>(
    onOk: (arg: OA) => OR,
    onErr: (arg: EA) => ER,
    fn: (...args: A) => OA,
    errorFn?: (error: unknown) => EA
) {
    return (...args: A): OR | ER => {
        try {
            const result = fn(...args)
            return onOk(result)
        } catch (e) {
            const error = errorFn ? errorFn(e) : (e as EA) // be true?
            return onErr(error)
        }
    }
}

Now with just a single function, the return type of (...args: A): OR | ER doesn't introduce a new type parameter (the A is from createSafeFn now).  We have to call it with more arguments now, but we finally get what you wanted:
const safeFn = createSafeFn(onOk, onErr, mayThrow)
// const safeFn: <E>(fail: boolean) => Err<E> | Ok<string>

So bad calls to safeFn are in error:
safeFn("oopsie", 123); // error, yay

And good calls produce everything you wanted to see.
const res = safeFn(true)
// const res: Ok<string> | Err<unknown>

if (res.ok) {
    const data = res.value
    // const data: string
}


So that's as close as you can get in TypeScript without new features in the language. You can write functions that act on other functions that, with some fairly strict caveats, produce new generic functions. You cannot abstract this to the type level (you'll find that TypeScript doesn't even let you write what you're doing as types. It would require type parameters whose scopes don't make sense, or higher kinded generic types). It's fragile and right at the edge of TypeScript's abilities.
Playground link to code
